# Fit in parallel but predict one by one - scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some code who fits a Linear Regression to some data. In particular I have only one feature (one-dimensional x) but several variables to fit on the same x-values (two-dimensional y). I can then take advantage of parallelisation by fitting the whole y matrix at the same time.

The issue is that I than would like to store the predictors independently so that I can predict only one selected variable and not all the variables I fitted.

Here follows some code example :

```
#Generation of x and y
x = np.linspace(0,10,num=11).reshape(-1,1)
y = []

for i in range(5) :
    coef = np.random.rand(2)*10
    y.append(x*coef[0]+coef[1])
y = np.concatenate(y,axis=1)

#Linear regression fit
lin_reg = linear_model.LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
lin_reg.fit(X=x,y=y)
```

If I run `lin_reg.predict(x)` I get all the variables predicted (a 2D matrix). I would like to being able to save somewhere (in a DataFrame, but that's not an issue) the `sub-prediction function`, as if I could store `lin_reg[i]` or `lin_reg.predict[i]`, which I could call to only predict the 1D array corresponding to the selected variable.

Is that possible ?

Comment: In your example, `lin_reg.coef_` and `lin_reg.intercept_` will have separate estimates for each `y` dimension.  You could implement a separate prediction for each, if you want.

Comment: ... with something like `predict0 = lambda x: np.dot(x, lin_reg.coef_[0]) + lin_reg.intercept_[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @rickhg12hs, that's exactly the workaround that I implemented. But in my question I anticipate the case where the predictor is not linear...so the coef and the intercept are not sufficient. I would like to have a generic solution.

Comment: Looking at the source code on GitHub, though not exhaustively, I couldn't find a "separable" `predict` method.  Picking the output of interest from `predict` may be the easiest and safest option.